# Exponential Linear Units (ELU) vs $log(1+e^x)$ as the activation functions of deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, activation-function

It seems ELU (Exponential Linear Units) is used as an activation function for deep learning. But its' graph is very similar to the graph of $log(1+e^x)$. So why has $log(1+e^x)$ not been used as the activation functions instead of ELU?

In other words what is the advantage of ELU over $log(1+e^x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReLU and all its variants ( except ReLU-6 ) are linear i.e $ y = x $ for values greater than or equal to 0.

This gives ReLU and specifically ELU an advantage like:

- Linearity means that the slope does not plateau or saturate when $x$ becomes larger. Hence, the vanishing gradient problem is solved.

[image]

Now, the graph $ y = log( 1 + e^x ) $ isn't linear for values > 0.

For larger negative values, the graph produces values which are very close to zero. This is also found in sigmoid where larger values produce a fully saturated activation. Hence, $ y = log( 1 + e^x ) $ can raise problems which sigmoid and tanh suffer.

**About ELU:**

[image]

ELU has a log curve for all negative values which is $ y = \alpha( e^x - 1 )$. It does not produce a saturated firing for some extent but saturates for larger negative values.

See [here](https://medium.com/p/b83ca804f1f7) for more information.

> Hence, $ y = log( 1 + e^x ) $ is not used because of early saturation
>   for negative values and also non linearity for values > 0. This may
>   produce problems and even bring down some features which ReLU and
>   variants exhibit.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But still I am not convinced. log(1+exp(x)), although it is non linear, it does not saturate for x>0. Do you say log(1+exp(x)) has early saturation for x<0 compared to ELU?

Comment: For all values > 0, log(1+exp(x)) is a non-linear function whereas ReLU is linear ( y = x ). For large negative values, the value of log(1+exp(x)) becomes closer to zero, which indeed is a problem suffered by sigmoid too.

Comment: For the potential saturation of negative inputs into ELU, is it less severe than sigmoid (both sides)? Then is parametric ReLU probably better than ELU?